# Graphql - How to include schema from other types

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

Let us say I have the following type:

```
type Foo {
  id: ID!
  field1: String
}
```

Now, I wish to define another type, which includes the earlier type. Something like this:

```
type Bar {
  ...Foo,
  field2: String
}
```

How do I achieve the above in graphql? I want to basically first create a type, and then include that type in the definition of other types so that I don't have to type all the attributes multiple times.

I am using [Amplify](https://docs.amplify.aws/) / AWS Appsync so if there's any special directive that I could use that would also be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GraphQL has the concept [interfaces](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#interfaces) for this.  Appsync, AWS's GraphQL implementation, [supports interfaces](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/interfaces-and-unions.html).

[Edit:] GraphQL does not support "...spread" syntax for interfaces.  Fields are defined explicitly.  Spread syntax does figure in GraphQL, but in the form of [Fragments](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#fragments), resuable units of fields for reducing repetition in queries.

```
interface Character {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  friends: [Character]
  appearsIn: [Episode]!
}

type Human implements Character {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  friends: [Character]
  appearsIn: [Episode]!
  starships: [Starship]
  totalCredits: Int
}

type Droid implements Character {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  friends: [Character]
  appearsIn: [Episode]!
  primaryFunction: String
}
```

Amplify, which automagically creates AppSync schemas, resolvers and data sources, is apparently a more difficult story.  The `amplify-cli` repo has an open feature request, [Does the GraphQL Transformer support interfaces?](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/202).  I am no Amplify expert, but a quick look at the loooong feature request comment thread suggests the answer for Amplify is *"not out-of-the-box"*, but *"maybe works in narrow circumstances or with advanced customization"*.

Comment: This requires me to define the attributes again in each type that implements the interface. I am looking at not typing the same attributes again - just "import"ing it, if that makes sense

Comment: No, the GraphQL spec does not support your syntax in type definitions.  Fields are explicitly defined in the schema.  The "...spread" syntax does figure in GraphQL, but in the form of [Fragments](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#fragments), resuable units of fields for reducing repetition in _queries_.

Comment: I see. Can you edit your answer with the above - I'll mark it as accepted